# Need to create the comment in dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Hi I need to create the dropdown option with the comment like below:

[image]

In that Admin are the users, which will come once starting to type the name "admin". As like for all searching user the comment needs to come as like above

Here is my code I have tried:

```
$( function() {
   var availableTags = [
     "ActionScript",
     "AppleScript",
     "Asp",
     "BASIC",
     "C",
     "C++",
     "Clojure",
     "COBOL",
     "ColdFusion",
     "Python",
     "Ruby",
     "Scala",
     "Scheme"
   ];
   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
     source: availableTags
   });
 } );

<div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Please provide me the suggestion for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
     source: availableTags,
open: function () {
                if (!$('#auto').length) {
                                                $('<li id="auto">Continue typing to refine further </li>').appendTo('ul.ui-autocomplete');
                                        }
                                    }

   });
```

Please try this